# How to use jprofiler on a multi server/jvm environment?

Tags: jprofiler

I'm trying to use Jprofiler in SIT/UAT environment.  Only problem is there are multiple instances running.  So fare in dev i was able to use it easily.  Is ther a way to configure and profile on multi jvm env.  where the request can go to any of the JVMs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use JProfiler to profile multiple VMs, but this means that you have to open a new window for each profiled JVM. Certain calls like web services, EJBs and RMI calls are tracked between JVMs, and you can click on hyperlinks in the call tree to jump over JVM boundaries.

However, there is no aggregated view of what happens in multiple VMs. In a scenario with many VMs it's better to use a monitoring product like [perfino](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/perfino/overview.html).

Disclaimer: My company develops both JProfiler and perfino.

Comment: i'm not talking about from app layer to webservice layer.. but for same applicaiton multiple instances running.. do i need to install it on all JVMs?

Comment: Yes, you have to add the VM parameter for profiling (-agentpath:...) to all VMs. For multiple VMs running on the same machine, you have to assign different ports.

Comment: But then i would need seperate window for each JProfiler?